# Django: Live Server Not Loading Images

Tags: django, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to deploy my school project on server, everything is working fine except the images are not showing up.

Here's my main project `urls.py`,

```
urlpatterns = [
    # common urls
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here's settings.py

```
Debug = False

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'project/media')
```

Template,

```
<img src="{{ data.image.url }}" class="Images" />
```

Everything worked fine when I was developing it, images were being loaded very well. But on the Live server, it's not loading the images.

Comment: Have you tried `python manage.py collectstatic` ?

Comment: @Arun Yes, sir I tried it. After doing so CSS starting working but images didn't.

Comment: Can you check the `STATIC_ROOT` folder, did the images are inside the directory? Or inspect the `src` attribute of the image and request the file directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change to:

```
urlpatterns = [
#common urls
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```